# Optimizing Reversal of Items

Tags: c++, optimization, vectorization

I have a loop that reverses elements in an array.  I have simplified and reduced the problem to the following:

```
for (int x=0;x<w/2;++x) {
    int il =     x;
    int ir = w-1-x;
    type_copy l = data[il];
    type_copy r = data[ir];
    data[il] = r;
    data[ir] = l;
}
```

This code reverses the elements, but is rather slow.  For one thing, it can't be auto-vectorized since the array accesses are discontiguous.  For another thing, the accesses on the right hand side are backwards from an ideal cache traversal.  Lastly, there is probably some stalling because the load for the next loop cycle can't happen before the data from the last one was committed, since the compiler probably can't tell that the self-aliased pointer doesn't ever hit itself.

In my case, `sizeof(type_copy)` is either `4*sizeof(uint8_t)` = `4` or else `4*sizeof(float)` = `4*4` = `16`.  Therefore, note that byte-level reversal is unacceptable.

My question is: **how can this code be optimized, iff it can be?**

Comment: Does this need to be in-place?

Comment: The end result does, yes. An allocated temporary is fine, although unless it is fixed size I doubt it will improve performance.

Comment: Why not just iterate backwards instead of reversing the physical order of elements?

Comment: fyi, what you currently have is probably identical to `std::reverse` after the compiler is done optimizing it

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::reverse` at least use `std::swap` to exchange the elements.

Comment: The implementation of `std::reverse` on my platform is indeed very similar to the above. What this question is really looking for is a more optimized algorithm that's cache- and vector-aware.

Comment: Backwards iteration will also be auto-prefetched on most platforms. Even strided iteration (for some strides).

Comment: Regarding SIMDization.   General swapping algorithms are vectorizable (with pragma simd or similar) in case source and destination indexes set are not overlapping. However yes, usually it will lead to irregular access pattern, which will lead to slow enough simd code, although in your case I hope some tricks could be done by compiler (if code is simple to disambiguate and track) or manually. Solution proposed by Pandrei looks slightly more "intrusive" for algorithm, but should end up by much better parallelizable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data types are like:

```
struct float_data
{
    float f1;
    float f2;
    float f3;
    float f4;
};

struct uint8_t_data
{
    uint8_t f1;
    uint8_t f2;
    uint8_t f3;
    uint8_t f4;
};
```

you can try SSE intrinsics. For uint8_t_data there is quite good speed improvement:

```
typedef uint8_t_data type_copy;

for (int x = 0; x<w / 2; x += 4) 
{
    int il = x;
    int ir = w - 1 - x - 3;

    __m128i dl = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&data[il]);
    __m128i dr = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&data[ir]);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&data[ir], _mm_shuffle_epi32(dl, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 1, 2, 3)));
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&data[il], _mm_shuffle_epi32(dr, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 1, 2, 3)));
}
```

Output:

```
g++ -O3 non vectorized: 16ms
g++ -O3 vectorized: 5ms
```

However for float_data not much speed improvement:

```
typedef float_data type_copy;

for (int x = 0; x<w / 2; x+=2) {
    int il = x;
    int ir = w - 1 - x - 1;

    __m256 dl = _mm256_loadu_ps((const float*)&data[il]);
    __m256 dr = _mm256_loadu_ps((const float*)&data[ir]);

    _mm256_storeu_ps((float*)&data[ir], _mm256_permute2f128_ps(dl, dl, 1));
    _mm256_storeu_ps((float*)&data[il], _mm256_permute2f128_ps(dr, dr, 1));

}
```

Output:

```
g++ -O3 -mavx non vectorized: 27ms
g++ -O3 -msse4.2 non vectorized: 25ms
g++ -O3 -mavx vectorized: 24ms
```

Comment: +1 for the nice solution and performance comparison! How many items did you use for the test? (I'm looking for better performance in the range ~100 to ~4000.)

Comment: 1024*1024*16 items. I used enough items to see the difference (tested on quite beefy core i7 avx2 machine).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code cannot be parallelized very well is because there is a dependency between the data:

```
for (int x=0;x<w/2;++x) {
   int il =     x;
   int ir = w-1-x;
   type_copy l = data[il];
   type_copy r = data[ir];
   data[il] = r;
   data[ir] = l;
}
```

There are 3 operations here: `compute l/r indexes`, `read from array`, `write to array`. Each one of these is dependent on the result of the previous operation so they cannot be done in parallel. Notice I group operations for left or right under the same category.

The first thing to do is try an brake that dependency.

Instead of reading ad writing in the same cycle try reading data for iteration N and writing data for iteration N-1; this can be done in the same cycle.

```
int il =   0;
int ir = w-1;
type_copy l = data[il];
type_copy r = data[ir];

for (int x=0;x<w/2;++x) {
   data[il] = r;
   data[ir] = l;
   il =     x;
   ir = w-1-x;
   l = data[il];
   r = data[ir];       
}
```

Or even better, precompute the indexes used for reading as well:

```
int il_0 =   0;
int ir_0 = w-1;
int il_1 =   1;
int ir_1 = w-2;
type_copy l = data[il_0];
type_copy r = data[ir_0];

for (int x=0;x<w/2;++x) {
   data[il_0] = r;
   data[ir_0] = l;       
   l = data[il_1];
   r = data[ir_1];
   il_0 = il_1;
   ir_0 = ir_1;       
   il_1 = il_1++; 
   ir_1 = ir_1--;
}
```

One other thing worth trying is copying more then one data sample; e.g read/write 2,4,..etc samples in the same cycle. This should improve the parallelism of your code.

Comment: +1 for the shift-loop-iteration 0.5 cycles trick. Can you perhaps add some explanation about where the dependency in my original code was, and how this helps? Would making two pointers to the left/right and declaring them `restrict` help? Maybe a performance comparison like doqtor's answer?

Comment: @imallett I added a few lines explaining the dependencyl; regarding the l/r restrict pointers - that is not a bad idea. The reason I did not point it out is that the effect of restrict is highly dependent on the compiler. And the compiler does not always consider two pointers on different locations of the same buffer as non-alias. But it's well worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it is better:

```
for (int x=0;x<w/2;++x) {
    std::swap(data[x], data[w-i-x]);    
}
```

If you don't prefer to use standard template library function, reduce the number of assignments and local variables as follows:

- Removed 3 local variables compared to your implementation
- Removed 3 extra assignment operations

`for (int x=0;x<w/2;++x) {
    type_copy l = data[x];
    data[x] = data[w-1-x];
    data[w-l-x] = l;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The code certainly can be optimized, but doing so might be platform dependent. For instance, AMD64 inherits a bunch of useful instructions from x86 SSE, including PSHUFD or VPPERM which can reorder words arbitrarily within a vector and MASKMOVDQU which can do combining partial writes.

Comment: At present, I'm trying to avoid assembly-level hacking, in favor of making things better for the auto-vectorizer. If you have any assembly-level tips, though, they might still be welcome. Targeting x86 and amd64 with SSE2.